# Solution of a backward stochastic differential equation

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-pde

In the paper [Adapted solutions of backward stochastic differential equations](https://www.i2m.univ-amu.fr/perso/etienne.pardoux/_media/papeng1.pdf) by Pardoux and Peng the authors prove in Lemma 2.1 that the stochastic equation
$$
x(t) + \int_t^1 f(s) ds + \int_t^1 (g(s) + y(s)) dW(s) = X, \quad t \in [0,1]
$$
has a unique solution. Here $W(t)$ is a $k$-dimensional Brownian motion with natural filtration $\mathcal F_t$, $f \in M^2(0,1;\mathbb{R}^d)$ and $g \in M^2(0,1;\mathbb{R}^{d+k})$ ($M^2$ is the class of $\mathcal F_t$-
progressively measurable processes indexed by $t \in [0,1]$ which are square integrable with values in $\mathbb{R}^d$ and $\mathbb{R}^{d+k}$ respectively), and $X$ is $\mathcal F_1$ measurable. By solution to the equation we mean $(x(t),y(t))$ (with values in $\mathbb{R}^d \times \mathbb{R}^{d+k}$) which is $\mathcal F_t$-adapted.

The unique solution, constructed in the proof, is given by
$$
x(t) = E(X - \int_t^1 f(s) ds|\mathcal F_t), \quad t \in [0,1],
$$
and
$$
y(t) = \overline y(t) - g(t), \quad t \in [0,1],
$$
where $\overline y(t) \in M^2(0,1;\mathbb{R}^{d+k})$ satisfies
$$
\int_0^t \overline y(s) dW(s) = E(X - \int_0^1 f(s) ds| \mathcal F_t) - x(0), \quad t \in [0,1].
$$

How can I show that such $(x(t),y(t))$ is a solution? How can I show that it is unique?

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I see it by the definition of $y$ you have $\forall t>0$ :
$$X=x(t) + \int_t^1 f(s) ds + \int_t^1 (g(s) + y(s)) dW(s)$$
$$X=x(t) + \int_t^1 f(s) ds + \int_t^1 \bar{y}(s) dW(s) (1)$$
And the term 
$$\int_t^1 \bar{y}(s) dW(s)=\int_0^1 \bar{y}(s) dW(s)-\int_0^t \bar{y}(s) dW(s)$$
$$= E(X - \int_0^1 f(s) ds| \mathcal F_1) - x(0) - E(X - \int_0^1 f(s) ds| \mathcal F_t) + x(0)$$ 
$$= X - \int_0^1 f(s) ds +\int_0^t f(s) ds - E(X - \int_t^1 f(s) ds| \mathcal F_t) $$

becomes in the end :
$$= X - \int_t^1 f(s) ds  - x_t $$ (because by definition : $x_t=E(X - \int_t^1 f(s) ds| \mathcal F_t) $

Putting this expression back into (1) everything collapse which proves the claim unless mistaken.

Comment: Thanks! I tried to do the same but made some error. Just one typo: in the second-to-last formula there should be $\int_0^1 f(s) ds$ instead of $\int_0^t f(s) ds$.

Comment: I corrected the typo thx for noticing